# How to get the literal representation of function argument?

Tags: python

I want to get a literal representation of function argument in exception message. Because x could be any object type, so there may be no str and repr defined for this type. Is there way to achieve that ? Thanks

e.g.

```
def f(x, y)
  raise Exception("<x> is not valid")
```

Comment: `'{!r} is not valid'.format(x)`? If they haven't defined (a sensible) `__repr__` you don't really have enough information to produce a plausible literal form. For some objects it may not be possible at all (i.e. if you can't pass in all state via `__init__`).

Answer (score 0):

As Johnrsharpe said in the commends a simple formatting should be fine for your use case.

For example if you have a class and a function.

```
class Myobj:
    pass


def f(x, y):
    raise Exception("{!r} is not valid".format(x))


f(Myobj, 1)
```

You should be able to get the output and a nice traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "42920465.py", line 9, in <module>
    f(Myobj, 1)
  File "42920465.py", line 6, in f
    raise Exception("{!r} is not valid".format(x))
Exception: <class '__main__.Myobj'> is not valid
```

You can see in the desciption the object that is being called is mentioned.